# Setting up MinGW in Paths

Tags: sublimetext3, mingw-w64

I know this question has been asked a lot (I have searched a whole ton but I can't find any solutions to the problem I'm having).

So I'm trying to set up MinGW to run .cpp files on sublime, and the error is the usual: 'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I followed the instructions and have set up MinGW only in C: to avoid spaces in the file path [MinGW set up in C:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLjgM.png) and have checked it through the cmd line where I still get the error [echoing path on the cmd line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCDpe.png). I honestly can't figure out what's wrong and googling has led me to the same result every time. Maybe I'm not picking up on my syntactical errors, I'm just starting out with this stuff. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Is there in fact a program called `g++.exe` in your directory `C:\MinGW\Bin`?

Comment: Hi Mike, sorry for the late response, but yes there's a g++.exe in C:\MinGW\Bin!